# Is it possible to compare strings in raptor?

Tags: raptor

Is it possible to compare strings in raptor? I've look in the documentation and googled, not haing any luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What type of string comparison operation are you looking to accomplish? Just a basic equality? Or are you looking at comparing a part of a string (e.g., starts with, ends with, or contains)?

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. I forgot to add quotation marks. Thanks for responding though.